# How to use user related data at Layout in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a site written on Asp.Net Core, and I want to use additional data related to the logged in user. So, each time a user opens a page, this data is loaded.
The problem is that I need this data in _Layout.cshtml, so I cannot use a controller, and I cannot use a code like this:

```
@{
    var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var data = await repository.LoadDataAsync(User?.Id);
    //Data usage...
}
```

Because it will be called each time a user opens a page with this layout.
I feel that there should be a simple solution, but I couldn't find it. Probably I should use a cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't be hard.

You can inject `UserManager<TUser>` into the page and use like below.

```
@inject UserManager<TheUser> userManager;
```

But you want to be sure that a user is actually logged in before attempting to do anything.

So, you can also inject the page with `SignInManager<TUser>`.

```
@inject SignInManager<TheUser> signInManager;

@

    {
    var user=await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    }
    if(user!=null && await signInManager.IsSignedInAsync(user)){
    //Do other stuffs with the user.
    }
```

Note that the `User` property:

> Gets the ClaimsPrincipal for user associated with the executing
>   action.

And it is available via `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` I guess.

Comment: I use similar approach right now. But I have several pages with the same layout, and each time a user goes to another page, I have to load the data. I wanted to load it only once when a user opens any page with this layout.

Comment: You need the user's data in your _Layout.cshtml so the same could be available in other pages using the _Layout? If so, you can just put your code in a partial view. That's if I understand you correctly. Something like :`await Html.RenderPartialAsync("UserPartial");`

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and I cannot seem to figure it out.  This explanation seems good but in the original question the guy says he cant use a controller, so where does the code from the accepted answer go exactly?  aka what 'controller' returns _Layout.cshtml